# From each group select 1 row that either matches or is a fallback

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

Using PostgreSQL 9.6, how do get I from data like this:

```
group | foo | value
------+-----+------
1     | A   | a
1     | B   | b
1     | C   | c
2     | B   | b2
2     | A   | a2
3     | B   | b3
3     | C   | c3
```

one row per `group` so that:

- if there is row with `foo = A`, take it,
- otherwise take any row from that group?

Example output:

```
group | foo | value
------+-----+------
1     | A   | a
2     | A   | a2
3     | B   | b3 <- chosen one row from group 3
```

Comment: Unrelated, but: "9.x" covers 7 major releases. It's not really relevant for this question, but you should specify the version a bit more precise (note that [starting with Postgres 10](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) the versioning scheme has changed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
t=# select distinct on ("group") "group", foo, value 
from table
order by "group", foo = 'A' DESC;
 group  |  foo  | value
--------+-------+-------
 1      |  A    |  a
 2      |  B    |  b2
 3      |  B    |  b3
(3 rows)
```

I think [neatest](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html) would be `DISTINCT ON`

Comment: Yes, this is the neatest indeed!

Comment: I think you need `order by "group", foo = 'A' DESC` - key change being the _descending_.

Comment: @vektor , yes - sure false is less then true

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT "group", "foo", "value"
FROM (
SELECT "group", "foo", "value",
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY "group" 
                          ORDER BY CASE 
                                      WHEN "foo" = 'A' THEN 1
                                      ELSE 2
                                   END, "foo") AS seq
FROM Table1) AS t
WHERE t.seq = 1
```

The query uses `ROW_NUMBER` with a conditional `ORDER BY` clause, in order to prioritize `'A'` records over the rest of the records.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/a07be/1)

Comment: See my own answer - it seems to be almost the same approach.

Comment: @vektor It would be interesting if you could compare all three suggested solutions and tell us which one performs better. I personally think the difference will be negligible.

Comment: I have partial results - my solution and Vao Tsun's seems ~ the same in terms of speed.

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to work for me:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  group,
  first_value(foo) OVER (PARTITION BY group ORDER BY foo = 'A' DESC) 'foo',
  first_value(value) OVER (PARTITION BY group ORDER BY foo = 'A' DESC) 'value'
FROM ...
```

If I need to specify the criteria by which to pick the fallback row I can do so by extending the `ORDER BY` clause, eg. `ORDER BY foo = 'A' DESC, foo ASC`.